# Is there a Laravel Sample App with authentication(ion or similar)+bootstrap+mongo support?

Tags: php, laravel

I am exploring the possibility of using Laravel in our startup. Looking to explore it through an app that provides above all to see how that behaves and how it compares to codeigniter framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found something with everything you request, but there are two excellent bundles for Laravel 3.2.1 that provide base platforms to build your apps.

1) bundles.laravel.com/bundle/orchestra

2) www.getplatform.com

Both have authentication / authorization, user management, and Twitter bootstrap support.

To my knowledge, neither works natively with Mongo, however, you may be able to plugin the Mongo Bundle

http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/mongor

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a package with all your requirements [specially Mongo], but if you are looking for row level authentication, I wrote a sample app which you can see on [my github](https://github.com/sirbijan/LaravelFullAuthentication). 
The little 'allowed' filter that I wrote ([app/filters.php](https://github.com/sirbijan/LaravelFullAuthentication/blob/master/app/filters.php)) allows you to define any permission you want for any page/link and then you can enforce it in your [app/routes.php](https://github.com/sirbijan/LaravelFullAuthentication/blob/master/app/routes.php) or blade template.